# Popping both Key and Value in dictionary while in a loop

Tags: python

```
for stallKeys in dictOfStallMenu:
    if not stallKeys == "Everyday":
        dictOfStallMenu[getStallName].pop(stallKeys,None)
return dictOfStallMenu
```

I am trying to pop items from a dictionary if it matches the condition. However, I am facing KeyError. I have tried to store in a different dictionary and pop the item out from it but it still shows me error. How can I resolve it?

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: Is the goal to retrieve the element popped, and thus to retrieve it in a variable or just to delete the element from the dictionary?

Comment: And what is `getStallName`??

Comment: You probably meant to iterate over `dictOfStallMenu[getStallName]`

Comment: share your dictionary data also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a new dictionary that has been filtered like this:

```
new_dict {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if my_filter(k, v)}
```

Where `my_filter` is a function that returns a boolean (`True` or `False`)